# Twitter API rate limit for OAuth based multiple users using Node Js

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

Is there any API rate limit for OAuth2.0 based twitter authentication.

I just wanted to know is there any API rate limit for OAuth based twitter authentication. Here we are fetching the user details like id,name..etc.

**Scenario**

**Consider**  1000 + people are are hitting my code to authenticate their twitter account . Is there any rate limit .?

I'm using node-twitter-api nodejs module for authentication

```
var twitter = new twitterAPI({
        consumerKey: appId,
        consumerSecret: appSecret,
        callback: "http://127.0.0.1/p/twitterAuthenticated"
    });
    twitter.getRequestToken(function(error, requestToken, requestTokenSecret, results){
        if (error) {
            logger.debug('Twitter : Error getting OAuth request token :' + error);
        }else {         
            req.session.twitterRequestToken = requestToken;
            req.session.twitterRequestTokenSecret = requestTokenSecret;
            var url = 'https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=' + requestToken;
            res.redirect(302, url);
            res.end();
        }
    });

twitter.getAccessToken(req.session.twitterRequestToken, req.session.twitterRequestTokenSecret, req.query.oauth_verifier, function(error, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, results) {
        if (error) {
            logger.debug('Twitter : Failure : twitterAuthenticated :' + error);
        }else {
            //store accessToken and accessTokenSecret somewhere (associated to the user) 
            //Step 4: Verify Credentials belongs here 
            twitter.verifyCredentials(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, function(error, data, response) {
                if (error) {                 
                    logger.debug("Twitter :: something was wrong with either accessToken or accessTokenSecret ");
                }else{  
                }
            }

        }
}
```

By looking twitter documentation, I got below details.

### Requests / 15-min window (user auth)  : 15

Is there any API rate limit per day basis to OAuth based authentication for multiple users

Comment: I think the 15-requests-per-15-minutes is the rate limit.

Comment: Thanks. Whether it is for individual or  multiple user..?

Comment: I would think per app key.

Comment: I have created single App in twitter app section and tested. I looking about how many user can login at the same time using this twitter app.How could i support multiple users.

Comment: I think you can _authenticate_ 15 users per minute, but the Twitter docs state that an access token doesn't expire. So once a user has authenticated, and they don't revoke access to your app, can you can accommodate an infinite amount of users.

Comment: Thanks.we are allowing 1000 + different people to authenticate twitter account at the same time. so all are different user, obviously we get different access token. Basically, i am looking how could i support 1000 + different people to hit my code and do the authentication.

Comment: Use multiple app keys perhaps?

Comment: I'm using only Consumer Key (API Key)  and Consumer Secret (API Secret). We can't create multiple app key for single twitter app.